# Laravel with JWT Auth: Get error message with status code

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, error-handling, vue.js, jwt

I try to implement JWT Auth in my Laravel + Vue SPA.

In my Controller I check the credentials like

```
try {
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(
                [
                    'error' => 'Invalid Credentials',
                ], 401
            );
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(
            [
                'error' => 'Could not create token!',
            ]
        );
    }

    return response()->json(
        [
            'token' => $token,
        ]
    );
```

My API call look like this:

```
axios.post('/api/user/signin', payload)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
```

If I pass valid credentials with the `payload` I get the token in the `then` block and can log this in the console.

If I pass invalid credentials I get an error in the console:

> Error: Request failed with status code 401
>      at createError (app.js:10562)
>      at settle (app.js:21378)
>      at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:10401)

How I can get the error "Invalid Credentials"? If I remove the status code from the response or set it to 200 I get the error "Invalid Credentials".

[image: Error with Status]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `response` key of error. To get the response.

```
axios.post('/api/user/signin', payload)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.response)
    })
```

Check Here : https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#012x---0130

Comment: Oh man, I'm feeling so dumb right now...I thought, since the error is output as a string, there is no object... Thank you so much!